# PHP form validation number fields

Tags: php, html, validation

I need this field to only allow numbers to be input to the field and there must be 11 digits that have been input into the "Mobile Number" field, this is the form I have created

```html
<form name="myForm" id="userDetails" action="formProcess.php" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <fieldset class="custInf">
    <h3> User Details </h3>

    <label class="inputArea" for="fName">Forename :</label>
    <input type="text" name="forename" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="20" size="15"></input>

    <label class="inputArea" for="sName">Surname :</label>
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="20" size="15"></input>

    <label class="inputArea" for="email">Email :</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" maxlength="40" size="15" /></input>

    <label class="inputArea" for="hmph">Landline number :</label>
    <input type="tel" name="landLineTelNo" id="hmphone" placeholder="Enter Landline no." maxlength="11" size="15"></input>

    <label class="inputArea" for=" mobileTelNo">Mobile number :</label>
    <input type="tel" name=" mobileTelNo" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter Mobile no." maxlength="11" size="15"></input>

    <label class="inputArea" for="address">Postal Address :</label>
    <input type="text" name="postalAddress" id="address" placeholder="Enter House no." maxlength="25" size="15"></input>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="contactType">
    <h3>
 How would you like to be contacted?
 </h3>
    <label class="radioBt" for="sms">SMS</label>
    <input id="smsBut" type="radio" name="sendMethod" value="SMS"></input>

    <label class="radioBt" for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sendMethod" value="Email"></input>

    <label class="radioBt" for="post">Post</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sendMethod" value="Post"></input>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="termsCon">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check" id="check" />I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy</input>
  </fieldset>

  <input class="submitBut" type="submit" name="submitBut" value="Submit" </input>
```

Here is the PHP I have created so far to validate the user input `//Ensures user enters information required

```
$fname = $_REQUEST['forename'];
if (empty($fname)) {
die("<p>Enter a first name</p>\n");
}

$surname = $_REQUEST['surname'];
if (empty($surname)) {
die("<p>You must enter a surname</p>\n");
}

$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
if (empty($email)) {
die("<p>You need to enter an email</p>\n");
}

$hmphone = isset($_REQUEST['hmph']) ? $_REQUEST['hmph'] : null ;

$mobile = $_REQUEST['mobileTelNo'];
if (empty($mobile)) {
die("<p>Enter a Mobile Number</p>\n");
}

$address = $_REQUEST['postalAddress'];
if (empty($address)) {
die("<p>Enter your postal address</p>\n");
}

$sendMethod = $_REQUEST['sendMethod'];
if (empty($sendMethod)) {
die("<p>Please choose a contact option</p>\n");
}

$check = $_REQUEST['check'];
if (empty($check)) {
die("<p>Please select the Terms and Conditions to continue</p>\n");
}`
```

Comment: javascript is the usual way to validate forms

Comment: *"there must be 11 digits"* I guess you never want to work with countries outside of North America?

Comment: You have to, no, make that *always* validate server-side. @Mihai

Comment: Use html 5 patern http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp and maxlenght http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp and then you can validate again with js functions and php functions

Comment: @JorgeMejia The second example there allows characters other than numbers and less than 11 characters. However I still agree with Jay Blanchard that you must validate server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can pattern match inside the form by adding the following code inside the relevant input field thanks to the html5 pattern tag. More details on the pattern tag here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

```
pattern="[0-9]{11}"
```

It's quite similar on the server side php checking thankfully!

```
$isValid = preg_match("/[0-9]{11}/", $formvalue);
```

$isValid will return true (1) if it matches or false (0) if it doesn't match.

preg_match is a very useful function in general for custom validation. There's more details on it available here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure your rule is correct you can do this:

```
if (empty($mobile) || preg_match('/^[0-9]{11}$/', $mobile) != 1 ) {
    die("<p>Enter a Mobile Number</p>\n");
}
```

from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

The regular expression explained:

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `[0-9]` match a single character present in the list below
- Quantifier: `{11}` Exactly 11 times
- `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- `$` assert position at end of the string

Comment: Even though it's not what OP asked for, I would do something like `$mobile = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $_POST['mobile']);` and just allow them to enter it any way they want. So if they do `+1 (123) 555-5555` it will still match correctly. Just make sure there are total 11 digits somewhere in the string.

Comment: This one has worked thanks mate:) I havnt checked others yet but this one does the job

Comment: I agree @Mike, I would tend to be more 'forgiving'.

Comment: Actually on applying the code, everytime i go to submit the form i keep getting the mobile error message... any suggestions?

Comment: I applied an edit or two @OliverQueen, did you get them all?

Comment: @JayBlanchard i applied your edits and its still coming up with "Enter a Mobile Number" when submitted

Comment: Are you using exactly 11 digits? In my testing I cannot replicate the issue @OliverQueen

Comment: @JayBlanchard yeah for example in the mobile field, i entered 12345678910 (11 digits) and still apearing`

if (empty($mobile) || preg_match('/^[0-9]{11}$/', $mobile) != 1 ) {
    die("<p>Enter a Mobile Number</p>\n");
}`

Comment: Sorry not to sure how i am meant to be adding code in comments @JayBlanchard

Comment: I just tested the code that you posted and it worked perfectly @OliverQueen Can you add `var_dump($_REQUEST['mobileTelNo']);` to your code, then post the form and copy the results here? We may need to do some cleanup of your posted data.

Comment: if (empty($mobile) || preg_match('/^[0-9]{11}$/', $mobile) != 1 ) {
    die("<p>Enter a Mobile Number</p>\n");
    var_dump($_REQUEST['mobileTelNo']);
 
}

Comment: @JayBlanchard used that code and its still coming up with the error message provided, i entered 11 numbers and still the error

Comment: Put the `var_dump()` *before* the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can validate with this:

```
if(empty($number)) {
    echo '<p> Please enter a value</p>';
} else if(!is_numeric($number)) {
    echo '<p> Data entered was not numeric</p>';
} else if(strlen($number) != 11) {
    echo '<p> The number entered was not 6 digits long</p>';
}
```